# c struct pointer array vs struct pointer pointer malloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

works:

```
struct data{
    int val;
};

int main(void){
    struct data *var[2];
    (*var)->val = 6;
    printf("%d\n", (*var)->val);
    return 0;
}
```

segfault:

```
struct data{
    int val;
};

int main(void){
    struct data **var = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct data));
    (*var)->val = 6;   // <- crash
    printf("%d\n", (*var)->val);
    return 0;
}
```

can someone explain why segfault appears and give me an working example with minimal changes to the segfault code that i can understand pls.

Comment: did you include `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h`?

Comment: sure, i don get warnings.

Comment: Yes of course you don't get warning, the compiler doesn't care and **can't** worry about the validity of pointers, and you didn't `malloc()` the `var[0]` pointer.

Comment: in linux ubuntu if use malloc without including stdlib i get implicint declaration ....... using var[0]??  i try that.

Comment: The 'wroks' example has undefined behaviour because the code is accessing offset from where *var points, but *var has not been set to point to any particular (like a malloc'd) memory area.  Therefore it is a seg fault event, just waiting to happen.  It all depends on what specific trash the stack contains where the struct data *var[2] happens to be pointing.

Comment: this line: 'struct data * var = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct data));' is allocating a memory area of 3 * the sizeof struct data and then claiming that it is an array of ** pointers to struct data. It should be: 'struct data ** var = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct data)); This allocates room for an array of 3 pointers. It needs to be followed by'" 'var[x] = malloc(sizeof struct data);' where 'x' is varied over the range 0..2 The result is BOTH of the examples have undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer is not `malloc`'ed, you are dereferencing an invalid pointer because your array is an array of poitners, and it's elements are not pointing to valid memory.

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data
{
    int val;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct data *var[2];
    /* You need to malloc before dereferencing `var[0]` */
    var[0] = malloc(sizeof(var[0][0]));
    if (var[0] != NULL)
    {
        var[0]->val = 6;
        printf("%d\n", var[0]->val);

        free(var[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

also, using `(*var)->val = 6` is absolutely unnecessary and confusing.

In the second case, you should also do almost the same thing, except that the array of pointers is a pointer to an array of poitners and hence needs `malloc()` too, so your second example accidentally works because there is enough memory `malloc()`ed but it's also wrong, you should do it this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data
{
    int val;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct data **var;
    var = malloc(2 * sizeof(var[0]));
    if (var == NULL)
        return -1;
    /* You need to malloc before dereferencing `var[0]` */
    var[0] = malloc(sizeof(var[0][0]));
    if (var[0] != NULL)
    {
        var[0]->val = 6;
        printf("%d\n", var[0]->val);

        free(var[0]);
    }
    free(var);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but if malloc returns valid memory .. then to what is var pointing to???Can pls give me an example with a malloc pointer pointer struct than i would understand.

Comment: @user3763903 now I see, your second example worked by accident, but it's not correct.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhh thx thanks , i understand now that first point **var to memory and than *var.. ok thx for example

Comment: this line: 'var[0] = malloc(sizeof(var[0][0]));' would be better/more clearly written as: 'var[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct data));'  and, just so there are no uninitialized pointers, followed by: 'var[1] = malloc(sizeof(struct data));'   of course, both memory allocations need to be free'd via: 'free(var[0]); free(var[1]);

Comment: 1. Clearly? may be... 2. Yes it would be good to initialize all the pointers.